# Moving all files in a folder to a new child directory

Tags: windows, powershell

In Powershell, how can I move all files in a folder to a new child directory?

I've tried mv `c:\foo\* c:\foo\bar\`, but all my files disappear and I get an extension-less 'bar' file. Making the directory first doesn't work either, as it will then try to move 'bar' to itself.

Comment: Try `mv c:\foo\* c:\foo\bar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily chain the `Get-ChildItem` (aliased as dir) and `Move-Item` (aliased as mv) to perform the move in one easy line. The only real trick is you need to specify the `-Destination` parameter (abbreviated as -dest):

```
dir c:\foo\* | mv -dest c:\foo\bar
```

One other thing worth noting, you may want to filter out directories - in your case bar is nested under foo - it wouldn't make sense to try and move it to itself and you will get an error. If you need to filter out directories you just pipe it through the `Where-Object` (aliased as the ?) cmdlet:

```
dir c:\foo\* | ? {-not $_.PSIsContainer} | mv -dest c:\foo\bar
```

The `$_` is a custom variable that points to each object in the pipeline as it is considered by the `Where-Object` cmdlet. The `PSIsContainer` property is a special note property added to the file system objects to easily identify something as a folder (or not).

It is also worth noting that in PowerShell v3 they added both `-File` and `-Directory` to the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet making it easy to skip the where clause entirely and just have it do that filtering initially.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want.  Create a variable named `$myDir` first that has the full path of your desired parent directory.

```
New-Item $myDir"\TestDirectory" -type directory
$files = Get-ChildItem $myDir\*.*
Move-Item $files $myDir"\TestDirectory"
```

Using a single `*` will also select child directories, which may have been part of your problem if you had inadvertently selected the new directory to be moved and also as the destination in the same action.  `*.*` should match for files.  Feel free to condense the statements once you're okay with what they're doing.

Comment: This solution taught me that you can use variables on the command line and that you can do things by hand that I would consider would normally be done in a script.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
Move-Item * childDir\
```

But it will give you an error like `Move-Item : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` because it tries also to move the childDir inside childDir (but it can't do it, as it's in use).

If you don't want to see the error (e.g. you are trying to use this in a DevOps pipeline where errors matter) you can use:

```
Move-Item * childDir\ -ErrorAction Ignore
```

This just works fine *but* if there is another unexpected error, you may not see it.